# Python Selenium ChromeDriver proxy not working

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, web-scraping

I have been trying to use proxy with Python Selenium on CentOS server.

I have same code on Windows 10 working fine as well.

I have same version of everything, Python, Selenium and ChromeDriver on both OS.

Here is my code.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % "http://198.55.109.17:3128")

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

Proxy is not changed at all, it just shows my own server's IP instead of the proxy's IP I am using

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there an error?

Comment: @roganjosh proxy is not changed at all, it just shows my own server's IP instead of the proxy's IP I am using

Comment: Have you tried to start with command line?if not try to do that.
--proxy-server=:

Comment: I have CentOS server and have only Terminal access, how do I do that?

Comment: try to start it with proxy server then

Comment: @Frrank can you explain how?

Comment: --proxy-server=:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144194/discussion-between-umair-and-frrank).

Comment: tried `google-chrome --proxy-server="http://example.com:8080"` but error is `[2996:2996:0514/124224.776561:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] Gtk: cannot open display:`

Comment: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy if  its not working https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1605

Comment: @Frrank But proxies work using same piece of code on my Windows

Comment: @Frrank Selenium + Proxies just sucks ... I tried every possible piece of code from internet and there is a NEW error each time ... I am giving up on proxies and will use it without proxies ... :(

Comment: @Frrank and using proxies from ChromeDriver gives a blank page, I took screenshot of it and it shows `No internet connection available` :(

Comment: Did you try `'--proxy-server=%s' % "198.55.109.17:3128"` ?

Comment: Without http:// and / at the and, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using proxies in selenium chromedriver is:

```
random_proxy = 'some random proxy'
[...]
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={random_proxy}")
[...]
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
```